# Appending zeroes to number using Regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a JSON with multiple data entries which I need to append three 0s to.  The Regex I've used to filter out the numbers I want to edit is: (?<=")[0-9]+(?=").  This should return all the numbers in the form "1234".  When I tried using perl on the command line, I haven't had much success.  The command I tried is:

```
perl -i -pe 's/((?<=")[0-9]+(?="))/($1)000/' input.json
```

Using any tool to achieve the result would be fine; I believe sed doesn't work since it doesn't have support for lookback and lookahead regexes.

Comment: More than 99% of the time, it is better to use the `JSON` module to manipulate JSON instead of regex

Comment: Why use '[0=9]' use '\d+' instead its more readable.   Also the numbers you get back can be modified with sprintf later on.

Comment: @alexmac: `\d` is very different from `[0-9]` unless you restrict the character set to ASCII using the `/a` modifier. `/\d+/a` is fine.

Comment: In perl '\d' is digits you don't have to wire '[0-9]' over and over every time, [perl regular expression meta](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Version-8-Regular-Expressions) and the link provides expressions.  My example shows you can match any number of digits \d+

Comment: A better example [here])(http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html) and I quote from the cheat sheet "\d matches any digit character, equiv. to [0-9]" , if in an interview someone does [0-9], that would be a down grade on their Perl skills as \d is more correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`($1)` surround the matched string with parentheses. Use `${1}`  as replace string. (`{`, `}` is required to distinguish group number from trailing `000`)

```
perl -i -pe 's/((?<=")[0-9]+(?="))/${1}000/g' input.json
```

BTW, you don't need to use positive lookaround assertion. Simply using capturing group:

```
perl -i -pe 's/"([0-9]+)"/"${1}000"/g' input.json
```

**UPDATE**

To replace all strings in a line, you need to specify `g` flag.

Comment: So I tried your command but it only replaces the first data point.  Am I missing a parameter to replace all the strings that match the pattern?

Comment: @RahinJegarajaratnam, If you mean you want replace all string in the line, use `g` flag. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a the \K to keep the `"123` part.

```
 perl -i -pe 's/"[0-9]+ \K (?=")/000/x'
```

Then you don't need to carry over any captured text. This requires Perl 5.10 or later.

Comment: This should be faster than capturing.

Comment: @ikegami: It will almost certainly be *insignificantly* faster

Answer (score 0):

You need the `/g` modifier to change *all* occurrences in the string.

It is also much easier to use the `\K` ("keep") metacharacter to avoid having to replace the number in the string. It is equivalent to a positive look-behind, but can accept a variable-length pattern.

You should use

```
perl -i -pe 's/"\d+\K(?=")/000/ag' input.json
```